# Finding the most k important features cv or split train/test?

Tags: feature-selection

my question can appear trivial for most of you, but i cannot find a definitive answer.
I have a tabular regression problem, with a large amount of features and the target variable. I am interested in knowing the most relevant features for the target.
I am evaluating the revelance of the features by model's importance (SelectFromModel sklearn).
Considering i am interested in the final features list, to evaluate different models producing different feature importance list, is it correct to use a pure cross-validation approach on the full-dataset or i should split the dataset and consider the score of the prediction on test set to avoid a possible data leakage in the selection procedure?

Example for LinearRegression

```
min_max_scaler = MinMaxScaler()
feature_selector = SelectFromModel(LinearRegression())
steps = list()
steps.append(( 'scaler' , MinMaxScaler()))
steps.append(( 'fs' , feature_selector))
steps.append(('model_predictor', LinearRegression()))
pipeline_with_selection = Pipeline(steps=steps)
cv = RepeatedKFold(n_splits=5, n_repeats=3, random_state=RANDOM_STATE)
scores = cross_val_score(pipeline_with_selection, X, y, cv=cv,scoring=('neg_mean_absolute_error'))
fs = pipeline_with_selection[:-1]
fs.fit(X,y)
features = X.columns[fs.named_steps['fs'].get_support()]
print('MAE: %.3f (%.3f) ' % (abs(mean(scores)), std(scores)))
```